# Jquery Plugin is not working when the source file is local

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe I am careless with sequencing the jquery plugins but I found it perplexing why is that the jquery plugin is not working when the source file is coming from local but when I try to use the cdn source it is working fine.

Here's the JS Plugin Structure [Non-working one]

```
<script src="./plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.13.0/js/fuelux.min.js"></script>
<script src="./plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="./plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="./plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="./dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<script src="./dist/js/demo.js"></script>
<script src="./plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

When I try to use the datetimepicker it return a "Uncaught TypeError. datetimepicker is not a function".

When I use the cdn source file instead it works

```
  <script src="./plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.13.0/js/fuelux.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/js/demo.js"></script>
    <script src="./plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does the local file actually exist where you think it does? My guess is, it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe is the version of your datepicker... download the https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js and copy to your local.